# Can someone explain this replaceWithX(int numRes) method?

Tags: java, arrays

I am just starting to learn Java and I web-search most of my questions but I am unable to answer this particular question. I found this source code here in Stack Overflow I just could not recall where but this is the source code. How can I explain the method `replaceWithX(int numRes)`?

This is a working source code, I just want to understand this particular method.

```
`public class SeatReservation {
// create 2d array w/ 7 columns and 5 rows
// create another array
static String\[\]\[\] stringArray = new String\[5\]\[7\];

// declare variables
static int seatNum = 1;
static int i, j;

static void replaceWithX(int numRes) {
    // replaces the seat chosen with "X"
    int rowNum = (numRes-1)/7; // <============================THIS IS WHERE I AM CONFUSED
    int colNum = (numRes-1)%7; // <============================THIS IS WHERE I AM CONFUSED
    stringArray[rowNum][colNum] = "X";

// what does (numRes-1) / 7 do?
// what does (numRes-1) % 7 do?
// are these operators?
// what does it have to do with numRes?

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create scanner tool
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // puts int array values into string
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // loop through all rows
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) { // loop through all elements of current row
            stringArray[i][j] = Integer.toString(seatNum);
            seatNum++;
        }
    }

    // prints the array
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // loop through all rows
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) { // loop through all elements of current row
            System.out.print(stringArray[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    // loops reservation system
    while (true) {
        // asks for seat number
        System.out.print("Enter seat number to reserve: ");

        // reads input
        int numRes = Integer.valueOf(input.nextLine());

        // check if input is invalid
        if (numRes > 35 || numRes <1) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: INVALID SEAT NUMBER");
        } else {
            // checks if seat is reserved
            int rowNum = (numRes-1)/7;
            int colNum = (numRes-1)%7;
            if (stringArray[rowNum][colNum].equals("X")) {
                System.out.println("Seat is taken");
            }
            // reserves seat if not reserved
            else {
                replaceWithX(numRes);
                System.out.println("Seat successfully reserved");
            }
        }
        // prints new array
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // loop through all rows
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) { // loop through all elements of current row
                System.out.print(stringArray[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

int rowNum = (numRes-1)/7;
int colNum = (numRes-1)%7;

I am confused whether it is an operator or something else. Why do we have to add this -1, /7, and %7?

Does it have to always be -1, or can it be any numbers? If not why?

Does it have to always be /7 or %7, or can it be any numbers? If not why?

Comment: Java counts from `0`. That is why you need `- 1`. Division by `7` is simply division by `7`; not sure what is confusing you there. The other operator (`%`) performs the modulus operation. That is commonly called the "remainder".

Comment: The thing with `rowNum` is that even though `(numRes-1)/7` may not produce an exact integer, it will record an exact integer, since `rowNum` is defined as `int`. So this number contains the "number of times it fully divides into the larger number", and `colNum` contains the "remainder".

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you familiarize yourself with Java operators, but here's what the program does:

`rowNum` is equal to `numRes` subtracted by `1` over `7`. So if `numRes` is equal to `15`, `rowNum` would be equal to `2`.

`colNum` is equal to the remainder of `numRes` subtracted by `1` over `7`. This means that if `numRes` equals `15`, the answer would be `0` because `(15 - 1) / 7)` equals `2` with a remainder of `0`.

Then the program replaces the object at the index of `[rowNum][colNum]` with `"X"`
So if we had an array of 7 objects, and `numRes` is equal to `15`, then the object at `[2][0]` in `stringArray`. Here is what this would look like:
`{{*String*, *String* ...}, {*String*, *String* ...}, {"X", *String*, *String*, *String*, *String*, *String*, *String*}, ...}` 
For further clarification, the first part of the array looks like this:
`{{*array of Strings*}, {*array of Strings*}, ...}`

So `stringArray[2][0]` would be the array of Strings at `index 2`. Then, inside the array at `stringArray[2]`, we look at the object at `index 0`. (`index 0` is the first object of an array).

Note that `rowNum` is an integer so even if the `numRes` is less pretty in regards to this equation, you'll still get a whole number. (i.e. if `numRes` equals `17`, even though the answer would normally be around `2.28`, `rowNum` would still be `2` because it cuts the decimal off. In this case, `colNum` would equal `2` as well because `7` goes into `16` twice with a remainder of `2`.)

If I had to guess, the `-1` and `7` are because the second dimension of the array has a length of `7`, so the last index would be `6`.
So an array of 7 objects would look like this (assuming the arrays object is equal to its index):
`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`
Because of this, using a higher or lower number may give an out-of-bounds exception or not have the possibility to capture all the numbers in the array, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Feedback: when coaching beginners, it's ideal to omit any expressions of surprise about how simple you find the topic. Similar advice is given to words like "basically" (hand-wavy) or "obviously" (it may not be).

Comment: As it's currently written, your answer is unclear. While it appears to be addressing the issue asked, it may be confusing for some readers to understand. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked.

Comment: @halfer Thank you! Sorry, I didn't realize I was being rude. I'll edit my answer :]

Comment: @RedYetiDev I was unsure what exactly you meant was confusing, so I tried my best to edit my answer - what parts of it were confusing?

Comment: I don't think it's rude as such - it's just that beginners sometimes report that they notice these phrases, and experienced educators tend to agree - it can be disconcerting if one is being told that material is simple when one actually finds it difficult. The challenge for experienced engineers is that teaching is a skill in itself (and one that few of us actually study in the formal sense).

Answer (score 1):

The 2D array created has five rows and seven columns, giving a total of 5x7=35 seats.

Here is the array declaration:

```
static String[][] stringArray = new String[5][7];
```

This is what the 2D array looks like as a traditional grid of rows and columns:

```
    0    1    2    3    4    5    6
0 [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ]
1 [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ]
2 [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ]
3 [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ]
4 [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] [  ]
```

From the code, it looks like they want the user to enter a number between 1 and 35 (inclusive) to represent the seats in the arrangement. The numbers go from left to right, top to bottom, like this:

```
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
    8    9   10   11   12   13   14
   15   16   17   18   19   20   21
   22   23   24   25   26   27   28
   29   30   31   32   33   34   35
```

To convert the seat number, 1 to 35, into a corresponding row and column number, we use the two formulas:

```
int rowNum = (numRes-1)/7;
int colNum = (numRes-1)%7;
```

Since arrays are zero-based, but the numbering system starts at 1, we offset the value by one. This is the reason for the `-1` in both calculations.

In the `rowNum` calculation, since both operands on either side of the division operator are integers, we are performing INTEGER DIVISION. This means that the fractional portion of the answer is simply truncated or thrown away; there is no rounding at all. Another way to look at integer division is to simply ask how many WHOLE times can the second number goes into the first.

If the user enters a value from 1 to 7, this would result in the values 0 to 6 after we subtract 1. Then you ask how many whole times does 7 go into that number. Since all the values from 0 to 6 are less than 7, the answer is 0 (zero) times. This give us the correct row number for the entered values of 1 to 7 as all of those numbers are in row 0 (zero) of the 2D array.

Looking at the second row, the user would enter a number between 8 and 14, which gets offset to 7 to 13. For that range of numbers, 7 goes into each of them exactly once, so the answer is 1, which is again the correct row for a seat between 8 and 14.

Following the pattern, the `rowNum` calculation will give you the correct row number between 0 and 4 for all of the possible seat numbers from 1 to 35. Note that the seat numbers listed below already have the 1 subtracted from them:

```
Seats  0 to  6 : 7 goes in 0 whole times
Seats  1 to 13 : 7 goes in 1 whole time
Seats 14 to 20 : 7 goes in 2 whole times
Seats 21 to 27 : 7 goes in 3 whole times
Seats 28 to 34 : 7 goes in 4 whole times
```

In the `colNum` calcuation, they are using the `%` operator which is commonly known as the "Remainder operator". You may also see it referred to as the "modulus" or "mod" operator. The `%` operator performs division as if it was a `/` operator, but then gives you back the whole value REMAINDER from that operation.

Here is the `colNum` formula again:

```
int colNum = (numRes-1)%7;
```

For example, let's look at the seat numbers present in the first column, represented by the set `{1, 8, 15, 22, 29}`. The formula first subtracts 1 from those numbers so our set is now `{0, 7, 14, 21, 28}`. Then we divide each of those numbers by 7 and get the remainder back.

```
7 goes into  0, 0 times with a remainder of 0.    0 = 7*0 + 0
7 goes into  7, 1  time with a remainder of 0.    7 = 7*1 + 0
7 goes into 14, 2 times with a remainder of 0.   14 = 7*2 + 0
7 goes into 21, 3 times with a remainder of 0.   21 = 7*3 + 0 
7 goes into 28, 4 times with a remainder of 0.   28 = 7*4 + 0
```

Note that for the seat numbers in the first column, we got the same remainder of 0 (zero) for all of them because they are all in column 0. Now let's a take a look at the second column.

The seat numbers present in the second column are `{2, 9, 16, 23, 30}`. The formula first subtracts 1 from those numbers so our set is now `{1, 8, 15, 22, 29}`. Then we divide each of those numbers by 7 and get the remainder back.

```
7 goes into  1, 0 times with a remainder of 1.   1 = 7*0 + 1
7 goes into  8, 1  time with a remainder of 1.   8 = 7*1 + 1
7 goes into 15, 2 times with a remainder of 1.  15 = 7*2 + 1 
7 goes into 22, 3 times with a remainder of 1.  22 = 7*3 + 1
7 goes into 29, 4 times with a remainder of 1.  29 = 7*4 + 1
```

Note that this time the remainder for all of the seat numbers in the second column was a 1. The 1 corresponds to the second column since arrays in Java are zero based.

Here are the results of each seat number being passed thru the `colNum` calculation. Note that the seat numbers already have one subtracted from them:

```
Column 1: {0,  7, 14, 21, 28} % 7 = 0
Column 2: {1,  8, 15, 22, 29} % 7 = 1
Column 3: {2,  9, 16, 23, 30} % 7 = 2
Column 4: {3, 10, 17, 24, 31} % 7 = 3
Column 5: {4, 11, 18, 25, 32} % 7 = 4
Column 6: {5, 12, 19, 26, 33} % 7 = 5
Column 7: {6, 13, 20, 27, 34} % 7 = 6
```

Also note that if the number on the left side of the `%` is less than the number on the right, you simply get the first number back.

In conclusion, the `replaceWithX()` method converts the seat number to the correct row/column in the 2D array using integer division and the modulus operator. We had to convert the 1 based values entered by the user, into zero based values by subtracting one. The 7 in the calculation was there because there are 7 columns in the grid.

```
static void replaceWithX(int numRes) {
    // replaces the seat chosen with "X"
    int rowNum = (numRes-1)/7; // <-- INTEGER DIVISION
    int colNum = (numRes-1)%7; // <-- REMAINDER OPERATOR
    stringArray[rowNum][colNum] = "X";
}
```

Final thought: It's important to remember that 2D arrays in Java are Row Major, Column Minor. This means the first set of square brackets, `[]`, accesses the row, while the second set of square brackets accesses the column. Thus in Java, when accessing a 2D array, the "coordinates" are written `(y, x)` as opposed to the traditional coordinate from math class which would be written as `(x, y)`.

With that in mind, I usually discourage the use of `i` and `j` to represent rows and columns. That's just confusing! Instead, make your variables names literally `row` and `col`, or `y` and `x`. People reading your code will thank you...  =)